# Zookeeper znode and watcher for /zookeeper/config, external access from outside java Client

Tags: apache-zookeeper

Where do zookeeper znodes reside?

After going through the apache zookeeper documentation, a zookeeper book, and googling I still can't seem to figure out where znodes physically reside in the computer( which directory or file in the computer do they sit in?).  I understand how to access them inside the zkCli.sh CLI with get and stat, that give me the details of a znode and their data, but after running a search for those /znodes, I get nothing returned.   Are these znodes not real directories/folders? Do they reside as fragmented elements spread across somewhere that I can't access conveniently externally?

What I want to do is set a watch on znode ZooDefs.CONFIG_NODE = /zookeeper/config. I know how to do that with "config -w", but I'm still not sure how to use the output of that watch to monitor a /zookeeper/config node change, i.e. how can I "pick up the signal" of that watch after its triggered and it's timestamp and set it into a variable, for instance.   (perhaps the simplest way is just use a python script that sends "zkClient.sh -server x.x.x.x:xxx stat /zookeeper/config" to the remote device and read the output?)

I read that the watch being triggered sends a callback, and this callback is a method one can write/modify, but I just simply want to know what the "config -w" watch outputs and where I can grab its "callback" or output signal.

Answer (score 1):

Actually these created znodes do not physically exist in a certain directory. Your assumption is right. Of course, you can not find such a directory/folder that keeps the znode. ZooKeeper uses in-memory cache and file/snapshot to store these data. You might recall that you have configure a option named dataDir, which is used to refer to the directory where the snapshot is stored, in zoo.cfg.

Below is the structure where my ZooKeeper (version: 3.4.6) resides. To be short, I've configured the dataDir identical with the source codes. You may find a folder name version-2, where the data files reside.

```
# tree -L 1 —charset ascii
.
|— bin
|— build.xml
|— CHANGES.txt
|— conf
|— contrib
|— dist-maven
|— docs
|— ivysettings.xml
|— ivy.xml
|— lib
|— LICENSE.txt
|— myid
|— NOTICE.txt
|— README_packaging.txt
|— README.txt
|— recipes
|— src
|— version-2
|— zookeeper-3.4.6.jar
|— zookeeper-3.4.6.jar.asc
|— zookeeper-3.4.6.jar.md5
|— zookeeper-3.4.6.jar.sha1
|— zookeeper.out
`— zookeeper_server.pid

9 directories, 15 files
# cd version-2/
# tree -L 1 —charset ascii
.
|— acceptedEpoch
|— currentEpoch
|— log.200000001
|— log.2000001f6
|— snapshot.0
|— snapshot.100000000
|— snapshot.200000123
|— snapshot.2000001de
|— snapshot.2000001f5
`— snapshot.20000050e

0 directories, 10 files
#
```

You may find the snapshot.* files, where you can find out the answers.

For watching on the znode, I recommend you write your own scripts with ZooKeeper Java API, ZooKeeper Python Client and etc. You can set a watch/hook on a specific znode and then process your scripts when changes are made to the znode.